# Get all the values for a specific field from a PowerShell text/json output file

Tags: jquery, json, powershell, pipe, export-to-csv

I have a huge text file output from a query in Powershell. Part of it looks like this. Now, I am interested in printing out/selecting only the numerical values of a specific field eg. costInBillingCurrency. I just want "costInBillingCurrency":0.003038455451812 out of the entire large text file.

```
"costInBillingCurrency":0.003038455451812,"costInPricingCurrency":0.0031903782244026,"costCenter":"","date":"2022-12- 00:00:00Z","exchangeRate":"0.9617696561673479201731185381101226","exchangeRateDate":"2022-12-01T00:00:00Z"
```

I want the output to resemble something like this so I can input it into a CSV file. I am having trouble forming the regex and finding the right commands to use in the Powershell terminal to form my script.

| header 1 | Values |
| --- | --- |
| costInBillingCurrency | 0.003038455451812 |
| costInBillingCurrency | 6.003038455451812 |

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: Just split on the first comma, capture that, then convert to CSV using the semi-colon as the delimiter and assign your header names. You can also, just drop everything after the first comma, then convert to CSV. This could have been done already in the PowerShell script that created your output. Yet, if this is a true JSON file, then export as JSON, and parse the JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, this is not complicated.

One way of doing this is:

```
Clear-Host
'"costInBillingCurrency":0.003038455451812,"costInPricingCurrency":0.0031903782244026,"costCenter":"","date":"2022-12- 00:00:00Z","exchangeRate":"0.9617696561673479201731185381101226","exchangeRateDate":"2022-12-01T00:00:00Z"' -replace ',.*' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header header1, Values
# Results
<#
header1               Values           
-------               ------           
costInBillingCurrency 0.003038455451812
#>
```

Or this way:

```
Clear-Host
('"costInBillingCurrency":0.003038455451812,"costInPricingCurrency":0.0031903782244026,"costCenter":"","date":"2022-12- 00:00:00Z","exchangeRate":"0.9617696561673479201731185381101226","exchangeRateDate":"2022-12-01T00:00:00Z"' -split ',', 2)[0] | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header header1, Values
# Results
<#
header1               Values           
-------               ------           
costInBillingCurrency 0.003038455451812
#>
```

Or if you really want RegEx, this.

```
Clear-Host 
([RegEx]::Matches('"costInBillingCurrency":0.003038455451812,"costInPricingCurrency":0.0031903782244026,"costCenter":"","date":"2022-12- 00:00:00Z","exchangeRate":"0.9617696561673479201731185381101226","exchangeRateDate":"2022-12-01T00:00:00Z"', '(?m)^[^\r\n,]+')).Value| 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' -Header header1, Values
# Results
<#
header1               Values           
-------               ------           
costInBillingCurrency 0.003038455451812
#>
```